# Multidimensional array C++.net CLI

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, multidimensional-array, c++-cli

```
array<int,2>^ a = gcnew array<int,2>(5,5);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

The above code is giving me the following two errors:

Error   1   error C3262: invalid array indexing: 1 dimension(s) specified for 2-dimensional 'cli::array ^'

Error   2   error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

Why is it so? :(

Comment: The correct tag is c++-cli, *not* cli. Please remember to review what the tag says it is when selecting.

Comment: @crashmstr: sorry i was new to this c++-cli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution!

Instead of using:

```
a[i][j] = 0;
```

It should be like this:

```
a[i,j] = 0;
```

Comment: Please check the time of my post and that of Vlad's ! He posted it 2mins after I had posted the solution. So did I have done something wrong..? :) BTW, thanks for the negative rep, just for posting the solution I found! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use trhe following form of indexing

```
a[i, j] = 0;
```